# Android WebView not load url on Android 4.2.2

Tags: java, android, webview

I have a WebView In my android application, this is how i set it settings:

```
    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
    cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);

    webview = findViewById(R.id.webView);

    WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();

    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);

    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

    webview.loadUrl(kDefaultAppUrl);
```

This is how I create the WebView:

```
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

When I run the app on my `Samsung Galaxy S8` it's run perfect, but I noticed that on an old `LG v500` Tablet(Android 4.2.2) it does not load the URL.

When I remove this line:

```
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

It loads the website but the website not loading properly, Any idea what is the problem?

Comment: can you share the url ?

Comment: try mWebview.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);

Comment: *the website not loading properly* - that is super vague. Any chance you could be more specific?

Comment: Did you find any solution ??

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```html
webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```